# Retrofit поменять параметры запроса по нажатию

Tags: java, android, retrofit

у меня есть запрос такого вида

```
Call<Responce> getProducts(@Header("X-AppId") String YOUR_APP_ID,
                           @Query("from") String from,
                           @Query("to") String to
);
```

**как правильно по нажатию на пункт меню поменять местами параметры в запросе** `@Query("from") String from, @Query("to") String to`

дергаю таким образом:

```
retrofit.create(myTrainInterface.class)
            .getProducts(APP_ID, FROM_CITY, TO_CITY)
            .enqueue/////
```

По сути можно просто создать отдельный метод с поменянными параметрами, но может есть более правильный способ что бы не плодить код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто в запросе смените переменные местами:
Те если было:

```
.getProducts(APP_ID, CITY_1, CITY_2)
```

поменять на

```
.getProducts(APP_ID, CITY_2, CITY_1)
```

Comment: Это как бы понятно. Вопрос как повесить смену , например, на кнопку меню ?

Comment: Для начала опишите условие задачи, что бы было понятно на что отвечать